# Incorrect average conversion

Tags: statistics

I have a table of values with one column representing a currency value (TTD) and a second column representing a second currency (USD). and third the conversion col1/col2

When I sum/divide the values I get a skewed conversion.

For example. Data below. My average of sum of first column/sum of second column is equal to 13.xx where as based on the values it should be 6.xx

```
1,818,822.07        289,997.70      6.271849984
203,409.53      32,225.84       6.312000866
-203,409.53     -32,225.84      6.312000866
-350                -55.45      6.311992786
-1,050.00       -166.35     6.311992786
14,222,605.73       2,253,264.53        6.312000007
1,301.64        206.22      6.311899913
15          2.39        6.276150628
-15         -2.39       6.276150628
-25.77          -4.1        6.285365854
-7,985,061.18       -1,271,020.82       6.282399985
-5,000,015.00       -795,876.58     6.282399967
5,199.72        827.66      6.282434816
-30,877.50      -4,878.19       6.329704255
-700            -110.59     6.329686228
-18,906,000.00      -2,986,871.42       6.329699991
18,906,000.00       2,986,871.42        6.329699991
1,190.82        188.13      6.329771966
-19,318,074.73      -3,067,943.74       6.296749995
-713,127.26     -113,253.23     6.296749859
-350            -55.9       6.26118068
2,381.76        378.72      6.288973384
-8,912.50       -1,429.89       6.232996944
-1,050.00       -167.95     6.251860673
-1,050.00       -167.95     6.251860673
-2,100.00       -335.9      6.251860673
-350        -55.89      6.262300948
-47,472.75      -7,565.80       6.2746504
-350        -55.74      6.279153211
36.04       5.73        6.289703316
1,080.57        172.09      6.279098146
-1,098,146.78       -175,401.79     6.260750133
-350        -55.87      6.264542688
-350        -55.54      6.301764494
36.04       5.75        6.267826087
-1,050.00       -167.44     6.27090301
-1,050.00       -167.44     6.27090301
28,338,750.00       4,492,082.24        6.308599996
4,378.13        693.99      6.308635571
-28,873,016.37      -4,591,217.07       6.288750005
-23,582.06      -3,747.41       6.292895627
-1,050.00       -167        6.28742515
-1,050.00       -167        6.28742515
16,716.08       2,655.66        6.294510592
5,185,813.44        823,007.82      6.301050019
-659,911.72     -104,515.64     6.313999704
-23,657.25      -3,765.04       6.28339938
-350        -55.52      6.304034582
-350        -55.67      6.28704868
7,768.40        1,231.98        6.305621845
-350        -55.65      6.289308176
6,925.14        1,098.64        6.303375082
-350        -55.74      6.279153211
7,678.17        1,212.39        6.333085888
-1,050.00       -166.32     6.313131313
-1,050.00       -166.32     6.313131313
-1,050.00       -166.32     6.313131313
-991,515.81     -157,705.13     6.287150012
-43,642.50      -6,925.46       6.301747465
-350        -55.73      6.280279921
5,925.17        941.16      6.295603298
-350        -56.02      6.247768654
5,936.43        939.81      6.316627829
-23,632.88      -3,756.77       6.290744443
27,843,640.00       4,428,095.01        6.287949996
-350        -55.57      6.298362426
-27,846,238.27      -4,409,992.84       6.314349996
19,460.05       3,080.75        6.316659904
-1,050.00       -166.46     6.307821699
-1,050.00       -166.46     6.307821699
-1,050.00       -166.46     6.307821699
-1,050.00       -166.46     6.307821699
-1,635,342.48       -260,353.03     6.28125004
-350        -55.55      6.300630063
4,470.03        706.55      6.32655863
24,092,464.18       3,810,802.37        6.322149994
-24,092,464.18      -3,810,802.37       6.322149994
-1,050.00       -166.76     6.296473975
-6,767.75       -1,074.84       6.296518552
-350        -55.53      6.302899334
24,055,140.00       3,808,211.63        6.316650002
-23,678.81      -3,755.74       6.304698941
2,608.93        412.98      6.317327716
-350        -55.59      6.29609642
1,177.84        186.47      6.316512039
-436,856.87     -69,364.38      6.298000069
-1,050.00       -165.88     6.32987702
-1,050.00       -165.88     6.32987702
-350        -55.63      6.291569297
122,188.28      19,364.23       6.309999416
-1,050.00       -166.16     6.3192104
946.25      150.15      6.302031302
-172,651.80     -27,449.71      6.289749509
-350        -55.61      6.293832045
37,230,180.00       5,892,622.78        6.318100002
-37,330,700.00      -5,937,902.13       6.286849999
-1,050.00       -166.13     6.320351532
-23,687.44      -3,747.86       6.320257427
-350        -55.54      6.301764494
9,151.40        1,450.01        6.311266819
11,293.06       1,792.46        6.300313536
-992,951.17     -157,159.77     6.318100173
-350        -55.45      6.311992786
-1,050.00       -166.48     6.307063912
-1,050.00       -166.48     6.307063912
52.47       8.32        6.306490385
-350        -55.53      6.302899334
-1,050.00       -166.32     6.313131313
662,928.00      104,937.67      6.317350099
-511,272.43     -81,005.84      6.311550254
-143,448.86     -22,727.99      6.311550647
-350        -55.45      6.311992786
-350        -55.49      6.307442782
-90.13      -14.29      6.307207838
-1,050.00       -168.09     6.246653578
-350        -56.03      6.246653578
-43,657.50      -6,986.21       6.249096434
-350        -56.81      6.160887168
27,220,600.00       4,386,775.50        6.205150001
9,002.18        1,453.24        6.194558366
-1,050.00       -170.2      6.169212691
-24,860,740.00      -4,011,640.83       6.197150008
-994,817.57     -160,528.24     6.197149922
-53,654.22      -8,657.89       6.197147342
-4,496.50       -724.8      6.203780353
-350        -56.31      6.215592257
28,014,300.00       4,495,811.40        6.231200001
5,639.16        906.36      6.221766186
-28,103,068.00      -4,513,896.46       6.225900007
-350        -56.18      6.22997508
5,703.84        915.77      6.228463479
-350        -56.17      6.231084209
919.7       147.09      6.252634441
-307,913.74     -49,281.18      6.248099985
-21,243.90      -3,400.06       6.248095622
-1,050.00       -168.36     6.23663578
-1,050.00       -168.36     6.23663578
-1,050.00       -168.36     6.23663578
-1,050.00       -168.36     6.23663578
-1,050.00       -168.36     6.23663578
-350        -56.04      6.245538901
731.57      116.97      6.254338719
-9,675.00       -1,541.50       6.2763542
-3,225.00       -514.53     6.267856102
55,062,480.00       8,773,499.04        6.276000003
-52,834,292.00      -8,479,127.60       6.231100001
-2,775.00       -443.09     6.262835993
-662,281.85     -105,643.94     6.268999907
-925        -147.53     6.269911205
8,491.00        1,353.61        6.272855549
15,953.21       2,553.82        6.246802829
-925        -147.84     6.256764069
2,285.13        364.67      6.266295555
-2,775.00       -444.55     6.242267461
-2,775.00       -444.55     6.242267461
-925        -148.08     6.246623447
1,617.09        258.89      6.246243578
-925        -147.57     6.268211696
-2,775.00       -443.13     6.262270665
-2,775.00       -443.13     6.262270665
1,789.42        283.87      6.303660126
-746,800.12     -118,907.75     6.280499967
-48,174.17      -7,670.44       6.280496295
-12,320.00      -1,963.21       6.275436657
-925        -147.95     6.2521122
1,202.42        191.05      6.293745093
-20,853.00      -3,319.59       6.281799861
-744,646.65     -118,569.59     6.280249852
-157.51     -25.08      6.28030303
-30,610.55      -4,874.10       6.28024661
157.51      25.09       6.27779992
-2,775.00       -442.7      6.268353287
-925        -146.85     6.298944501
747.97      118.98      6.286518743
-17,932.00      -2,852.89       6.28555605
-925        -147.2      6.283967391
38,412,310.00       6,102,325.77        6.294699996
2,800.09        444.83      6.294741811
-181,166.18     -28,846.51      6.280350032
-2,775.00       -438.51     6.32824793
-2,775.00       -438.51     6.32824793
-925        -146.83     6.299802493
-38,861,992.00      -6,175,382.68       6.293050004
-15     -2.38       6.302521008
-925        -146.75     6.303236797
-2,775.00       -438.68     6.325795569
-925        -146.05     6.33344745
-2,775.00       -437.82     6.338221187
1,266,320.00        200,422.59      6.318249854
68.43       10.79       6.341983318
-749,899.63     -117,996.87     6.355250186
-925        -145.53     6.356077785
-2,775.00       -438.4      6.329835766
-2,775.00       -438.4      6.329835766
-925        -145.97     6.336918545
27,914,920.00       4,400,104.03        6.344150004
276.38      43.56       6.344811754
-27,460,620.00      -4,327,028.35       6.346299996
-925        -145.86     6.341697518
-2,775.00       -436.66     6.355058856
-2,775.00       -436.66     6.355058856
2,651.32        417.04      6.357471705
-386,493.56     -60,731.23      6.364000202
-925        -145.54     6.355641061
29.77       4.7     6.334042553
-2,775.00       -438.35     6.330557773
-925        -146.23     6.325651371
-2,775.00       -437.07     6.349097399
-925        -145.85     6.342132328
-387,637.80     -61,349.66      6.318499565
-925        -145.86     6.341697518
-2,775.00       -436.94     6.350986405
-20,278.00      -3,196.99       6.342841235
-30,237.00      -4,748.12       6.368204679
-2,775.00       -437.99     6.33576109
-925        -145.84     6.342567197
-925        -145.86     6.341697518
636,290.00      100,044.81      6.360050062
-161,861.27     -25,499.20      6.347699928
-608,290.04     -95,570.21      6.364849884
-925        -145.71     6.348225928
1,265,560.00        199,150.25      6.354799956
-354,817.53     -56,152.68      6.318799566
109,190,760.00      17,134,950.73       6.372399998
-1,875.00       -294.39     6.369102211
-31,374,180.00      -4,920,243.71       6.376549994
-253,987.74     -39,831.53      6.376549934
-74,873,520.00      -11,742,010.96      6.376550001
5,145.76        806.98      6.376564475
-1,875.00       -292.68     6.406314063
-4,650.00       -727.86     6.388591213
-2,800.00       -435.76     6.425555352
-24,625.00      -3,842.70       6.408254613
-19,200.00      -2,996.14       6.408245276
-109,325.20     -17,030.31      6.419448618
-2,800.00       -436.17     6.419515327
-81,180.18      -12,676.48      6.404000164
-26,005.00      -4,074.29       6.382707171
-2,800.00       -439.05     6.377405762
-30,750.00      -4,803.82       6.401155747
-2,800.00       -437.72     6.396783332
-20,294,100.00      -3,159,229.42       6.423750004
-100        -15.57      6.422607579
-563,755.47     -88,061.34      6.401849779
-2,800.00       -437.82     6.395322279
26.62       4.17        6.383693046
-2,800.00       -437.06     6.406443051
-2,800.00       -437.34     6.402341428
-25,200.00      -3,924.38       6.421396501
-289,647.27     -45,521.62      6.362850663
-2,800.00       -437.31     6.402780636
86,467,500.00       13,491,995.38       6.408800001
-2,800.00       -436.99     6.407469278
30.95       4.84        6.394628099
-81,123,453.00      -12,702,432.96      6.386450002
-100        -15.66      6.385696041
-2,800.00       -436.14     6.419956895
-357,672.64     -55,986.08      6.388599452
-16,800.00      -2,623.44       6.40380569
-2,800.00       -437.28     6.403219905
-33,600.00      -5,254.10       6.395005805
-2,800.00       -438.87     6.380021419
-2,800.00       -437.38     6.40175591
-44,758.00      -6,975.07       6.416853164
44,758.00       6,975.07        6.416853164
-8,400.00       -1,309.05       6.416867194
-253,204.75     -39,607.18      6.392900227
44,758.00       6,980.95        6.411448299
-44,758.00      -6,980.95       6.411448299
-44,773.00      -7,016.23       6.381347248
-5,109.50       -798.7      6.397270565
-2,800.00       -437.68     6.39736794
-235,989.46     -36,816.98      6.4097995
190,481.13      29,717.17       6.409800462
-141,610.54     -22,108.17      6.405348792
-2,800.00       -436.58     6.413486646
-16,800.00      -2,619.47       6.41351113
141,610.54      22,108.17       6.405348792
-2,800.00       -436.92     6.408495834
-87,229.11      -13,611.05      6.40869808
-2,800.00       -436.42     6.415837954
80,083,750.00       12,457,901.33       6.428349999
-8,400.00       -1,309.76       6.413388712
237,516.32      37,034.38       6.413400737
-100        -15.68      6.37755102
-85,142,547.00      -13,347,423.48      6.378949999
-16,800.00      -2,622.25       6.406711793
-2,775.00       -433.33     6.403895415
-925        -144.88     6.384594147
-2,775.00       -433        6.408775982
-925        -144.29     6.410700672
-338,131.90     -52,918.27      6.38970057
-925        -144.38     6.40670453
44,616.67       6,995.40        6.378001258
-925        -144.72     6.391652847
-2,775.00       -433.57     6.400350578
-100        -15.59      6.414368185
-116,316,863.00     -18,133,284.95      6.414550001
-2,775.00       -433.2      6.405817175
-2,775.00       -432.46     6.41677843
158,643.33      24,712.92       6.419449017
-8,325.00       -1,298.02       6.413614582
-59,229.04      -9,269.96       6.389352273
-925        -144.31     6.40981221
-2,775.00       -433.77     6.397399544
-2,800.00       -437.65     6.397806466
-5,625.00       -876.78     6.415520427
-5,625.00       -876.78     6.415520427
27,071.00       4,220.51        6.41415374
-27,071.00      -4,220.51       6.41415374
-2,800.00       -436.53     6.414221245
27,071.00       4,219.56        6.415597835
-27,086.00      -4,222.82       6.414197148
-2,800.00       -436.98     6.407615909
-21,671.80      -3,384.34       6.403552835
-179,791.33     -28,068.71      6.405400533
-2,775.00       -433.23     6.405373589
-5,625.00       -878.17     6.405365704
-2,775.00       -433.23     6.405373589
-2,775.00       -433.23     6.405373589
-6,119.20       -955.1      6.406868391
-130,549.71     -20,376.42      6.406901212
-5,625.00       -877.96     6.406897809
-2,800.00       -435.28     6.432641059
-2,775.00       -431.39     6.432694314
-5,625.00       -878.27     6.404636387
-2,800.00       -435.8      6.424965581
32,043,500.00       4,987,315.18        6.424999994
-2,775.00       -432.72     6.412922906
-2,775.00       -432.72     6.412922906
-184,988.40     -28,846.29      6.412900931
-5,625.00       -877.14     6.412887338
-32,322,652.00      -5,040,255.11       6.412900001
-100        -15.59      6.414368185
-2,800.00       -437.14     6.405270623
-2,775.00       -432.17     6.421084296
-2,775.00       -432.17     6.421084296
-5,625.00       -875.15     6.427469577
-2,800.00       -435.63     6.427472855
-2,800.00       -435.15     6.434562794
-5,625.00       -875.05     6.428204103
-5,625.00       -876.24     6.419474117
-229,071.64     -35,745.53      6.408399596
1,468,274.48        229,117.17      6.408400034
-2,775.00       -431.74     6.427479502
-2,800.00       -435.68     6.426735219
-2,775.00       -432.38     6.417965678
-5,625.00       -875.48     6.425046831
-2,800.00       -435.48     6.429686782
462,895,200.00      71,927,838.34       6.43555
-362,832,536.00     -56,752,883.69      6.3932
-2,775.00       -434.97     6.379750328
-5,625.00       -873.26     6.441380574
-100        -15.52      6.443298969
-90,708,134.00      -14,076,807.78      6.443800002
-2,800.00       -435.8      6.424965581
-279,878.05     -43,522.85      6.430600248
-5,625.00       -879.58     6.39509766
-2,800.00       -436.66     6.412311638
-2,775.00       -432.94     6.409664157
-5,625.00       -877.6      6.40952598
-2,775.00       -431.77     6.427032911
-2,800.00       -435.85     6.424228519
-2,775.00       -431.51     6.430905425
-2,800.00       -436.58     6.413486646
-5,625.00       -877.06     6.413472282
-216,426.61     -33,506.20      6.459300368
-5,625.00       -873.77     6.437620884
-2,800.00       -433.25     6.462781304
-5,625.00       -872.61     6.446178705
-2,775.00       -430.14     6.45138792
-65,812.54      -10,201.36      6.451349624
-2,800.00       -434.22     6.448344157
-5,625.00       -875.13     6.427616468
-2,800.00       -439.51     6.370731041
57,336,300.00       8,987,514.79        6.379550002
-2,775.00       -434.98     6.37960366
-2,775.00       -434.98     6.37960366
-52,155,410.00      -8,205,309.69       6.356300002
-100        -15.73      6.357279085
-303,383.80     -47,731.12      6.35610059
-2,800.00       -441.55     6.341297701
113,328.52      17,810.41       6.363049475
-2,775.00       -435.87     6.36657719
-5,625.00       -887.63     6.337099918
-5,625.00       -887.63     6.337099918
-2,775.00       -437        6.350114416
-2,800.00       -441.8      6.337709371
-2,775.00       -437.14     6.348080706
-72,161.40      -11,367.49      6.348050449
72,146.40       11,356.72       6.352749738
-5,625.00       -886.97     6.341815394
-2,800.00       -442.18     6.332262879
-140,560.45     -22,096.01      6.361349855
-5,625.00       -886.55     6.344819807
-2,800.00       -441.93     6.335845043
-2,775.00       -437.58     6.341697518
-2,775.00       -437.58     6.341697518
72,146.40       11,410.06       6.323051763
-72,146.40      -11,410.06      6.323051763
-5,625.00       -885.67     6.351124008
-72,146.40      -11,359.67      6.351099988
-2,800.00       -440.87     6.351078549
-2,775.00       -436.54     6.356805791
-5,625.00       -884.94     6.356363143
-2,800.00       -439.05     6.377405762
-136,609.63     -21,465.33      6.36419892
-5,625.00       -887.62     6.337171312
-2,775.00       -438.34     6.330702195
-2,800.00       -440.49     6.35655747
113,211.12      17,871.02       6.334899743
-5,625.00       -887.06     6.341171961
-2,800.00       -440.14     6.361612214
-2,775.00       -436.96     6.350695716
-2,775.00       -436.96     6.350695716
-5,625.00       -888.03     6.334245465
-2,800.00       -441.74     6.3385702
-79,790.50      -12,550.21      6.357702381
-37,286.50      -5,891.00       6.329400781
-2,800.00       -441.42     6.343165239
-5,625.00       -885.66     6.351195718
-32,449.99      -5,130.31       6.325151891
-2,800.00       -441.49     6.342159505
37,996.00       5,994.95        6.338001151
-37,996.00      -5,994.95       6.338001151
-2,775.00       -437.88     6.337352699
-2,775.00       -437.88     6.337352699
31,738,000.00       5,003,349.96        6.343350006
-2,800.00       -442.79     6.323539375
-30     -4.72       6.355932203
-37,966.00      -5,974.48       6.354695304
-5,625.00       -885.46     6.352630271
-5,625.00       -885.46     6.352630271
-27,011,602.00      -4,248,510.04       6.357900004
-100        -15.73      6.357279085
-329,232.91     -51,965.14      6.335649437
76,312,800.00       11,993,116.51       6.363049999
-2,775.00       -436.11     6.363073536
-2,775.00       -436.11     6.363073536
-2,800.00       -441        6.349206349
-100        -15.82      6.321112516
-83,732,880.00      -13,248,663.79      6.320099999
-2,775.00       -438.71     6.325362996
-5,625.00       -887.08     6.341028994
-2,800.00       -441.97     6.335271625
19,024,500.00       2,996,597.73        6.348699997
-22,816,847.00      -3,593,940.02       6.348699999
-100        -15.75      6.349206349
-5,625.00       -887.16     6.340457189
-5,625.00       -886.21     6.347254037
-2,775.00       -437.21     6.34706434
-2,800.00       -440.95     6.349926295
-168,392.58     -26,576.06      6.336250746
-3,579.55       -556.89     6.427750543
-3,153.41       -493.51     6.389759073
-123,688.76     -19,232.46      6.431250084
-2,775.00       -431.49     6.431203504
-5,625.00       -872.84     6.444480088
-2,800.00       -434.48     6.444485362
-5,625.00       -870.97     6.45831659
-2,775.00       -428.15     6.48137335
-6,392.04       -986.21     6.481418765
-2,800.00       -430.49     6.504216126
32,986,500.00       5,000,644.29        6.596449995
49.38       7.52        6.566489362
-100        -15.22      6.570302234
-180,232.29     -27,432.41      6.570049442
-32,536,281.00      -4,952,212.08       6.570050005
1,455.27        221.28      6.576599783
224,147.35      33,839.69       6.623800336
24.69       3.72        6.637096774
-357,756.66     -53,776.56      6.652650523
-124,148.20     -18,483.92      6.716551467
-10,200.00      -1,521.91       6.702104592
-10,200.00      -1,518.91       6.715341923
-189,416.88     -28,216.64      6.712949522
-10,200.00      -1,512.59       6.743400393
-1      -0.15       6.666666667
-60     -8.85       6.779661017
-20,298,600.00      -3,008,291.90       6.747549997
20,298,600.00       3,008,291.90        6.747549997
-100        -14.83      6.743088334
-32,786,484.00      -4,860,893.56       6.744949996
-10,200.00      -1,506.49       6.770705415
-60     -8.87       6.764374295
-213,420.77     -31,701.96      6.73210016
-1      -0.15       6.666666667
-60     -8.86       6.772009029
-10,200.00      -1,508.16       6.763208148
-10,200.00      -1,507.42       6.76652824
-1      -0.15       6.666666667
-60     -8.9        6.741573034
-60     -8.9        6.741573034
-37,200.00      -5,506.99       6.755051308
-10,400.00      -1,542.50       6.742301459
-188,138.06     -27,773.76      6.773949944
-60     -8.89       6.749156355
-2,775.00       -436.96     6.350695716
-2,775.00       -436.96     6.350695716
-5,625.00       -888.03     6.334245465
76,312,800.00       12,000,000.00       6.3594
5,625.00        888.03      6.334245465
-2,800.00       -441.74     6.3385702
329,232.91      51,965.14       6.335649437
-76,312,800.00      -11,993,116.51      6.363049999
2,775.00        436.11      6.363073536
2,775.00        436.11      6.363073536
-203,409.50     -32,151.47      6.326600308
203,409.50      32,151.47       6.326600308
-203,409.53     -32,151.48      6.326599273
-15     -2.37       6.329113924
18,906,000.00       3,000,000.00        6.302
-36.04      -5.73       6.289703316
-24,092,464.18      -3,800,000.00       6.340122153
24,092,464.18       3,800,000.00        6.340122153
-24,092,464.18      -3,813,637.49       6.317450005
                0
                0
157.51      25.08       6.28030303
-157.51     -25.09      6.27779992
34,625.54       5,472.92        6.326703113
-15     -2.36       6.355932203
32,120,000.00       5,000,000.00        6.424
350,000.00      54,505.67       6.421350293
450,000.00      70,078.72       6.421350162
-700,000.00     -109,011.34     6.421350293
-350,000.00     -54,505.67      6.421350293
-450,000.00     -70,078.72      6.421350162
700,000.00      109,011.34      6.421350293
1,329,104.91        207,484.61      6.405799977
                13.2910491
114,854,400.00      18,000,000.00       6.3808
-27,071.00      -4,219.56       6.415597835
-2,800.00       -435.63     6.427472855
2,800.00        435.63      6.427472855
0.00        0.00        6.73555
0.00        0.00        6.73555
20,298,600.00       3,000,000.00        6.7662
-6,098.85       -919.01     6.636326047
-31,675.15      -4,773.01       6.636304973
-37,996.00      -5,994.95       6.338001151
-2,775.00       -436.9      6.351567864
30      4.72        6.355932203
-37,996.00      -5,989.00       6.344297879
37,966.00       5,974.48        6.354695304
2,800.00        441.74      6.3385702
2,775.00        436.96      6.350695716
2,775.00        436.96      6.350695716
37,996.00       6,013.88        6.318050909
2,800.00        441     6.349206349
2,775.00        438.71      6.325362996
-2,084,867.40       -329,232.91     6.332499992
-17,572.69      -2,775.00       6.332500901
-17,572.69      -2,775.00       6.332500901
-17,731.00      -2,800.00       6.3325
-17,572.69      -2,775.00       6.332500901
2,084,867.40        329,232.91      6.332499992
17,572.69       2,775.00        6.332500901
17,572.69       2,775.00        6.332500901
17,731.00       2,800.00        6.3325
17,572.69       2,775.00        6.332500901
-329,232.91     -51,990.98      6.332500561
-2,775.00       -438.22     6.332435763
-2,775.00       -438.22     6.332435763
-2,800.00       -442.16     6.332549303
```

Comment: there are a few rows near the end of your table that only have one entry. is that supposed to be the case?

Comment: Good spot, that was not the intention but a result of me manipulating the data to see if there was any possible correlation with those lines by essentially zeroing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from having positive and negative numbers in the first and second columns which almost cancel each other out, amplifying small differences in the ratio (perhaps the *bureau de change* or bank's commission leading to slightly different rates in each direction).

Just taking sums of the signed values you get something like $\dfrac{6,914,077.86}{531,223.31} \approx 13.015$  (I had to clean your numbers so this may be a tiny bit different to your result but the message is the same)

If you are looking for a *typical* exchange rate, you would do better to take the absolute values (i.e. make everything positive) before your averaging. The magnitudes of the sums are several hundred times larger

If you take sums of the absolute values you get something like $\dfrac{3,325,670,799.16}{521,020,658.61}\approx 6.383$   and this is a much more plausible typical value

As a simpler example, consider

```
 1206    200    6.03
-1194   -199    6.00
```

Just take the sums and your get $\dfrac{12}{1}=12$ as the net ratio but take the sum of the absolute value and get $\dfrac{2400}{399} \approx 6.015$ as close to the typical value

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly it.